# Keep only unique lines (names) from text file and remove the rest

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of names in a text file like below :

```
John Doe
John Doe
Carl Berg
Roger Hansen
Roger Hansen
Jane Doe
Lance Anderson
Lance Anderson
```

I only want to keep the unique names (the whole line) and remove the rest.
How do I do this with a batch script or maybe Notepad++?

Comment: This is not answered in any other post I could find. Other posts describe TextFX and Cygwin as a solution. I have tested but neither works.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, add a line break at the end of the file**

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+\R)\1+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of line
(       : start group 1
  .+    : 1 or more any character but newline
  \R    : any kind of linebreak
)       : end group
\1+     : backreference to group 1, must appear 1 or more times
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Carl Berg
Jane Doe
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Notepad++ says Replaces All: 0 occurences where replaced. I'm trying it on a list of names that is much larger. With 160 names with both two and three names.

Comment: @user2427836: What version of Npp, here I use 7.5.1 ? Are the names **really ** identical (ie. same number of spaces between firstname and lastname)? Are all lines ending with same number of spaces?

Answer (score -1):

In Notepad++, do a Find and Replace:

Find what:

```
(.+)[\r\n]+(\1[\r\n]*)+
```

Replace it with nothing.

Be sure to select "Regular expression" when doing the Find and Replace, and uncheck the box for ". matches newline".

### What if there are duplicate lines in the file that aren't grouped together?

Before doing the Find and Replace, do: Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending

Comment: @Toto Thanks, I misunderstood. I have updated my answer.